Zeros of the wavefunction and Hall Conductivity
I am recently reading the paper of Kohmoto, Topology of Hall Conductance (LINK).
At Section III of this paper, he argues that the phase of the wavefunction cannot be determined uniquely and smoothly in the entire magnetic Brillouin zone as follows:

Suppose $u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x, y)$ satisfies the Schrodinger equation
\begin{align}
\hat{H}(k_{1}, k_{2}) u_{k_{1} k_{2}}^{\alpha} = E^{\alpha} u_{k_{1}k_{2}}^{\alpha} \tag{3.1}
\end{align}
then so does $u_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x, y) e^{if(k_{1}, k_{2})}$ where $f(k_{1}, k_{2})$ is an arbitrary smooth function on $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ and is independent of $x$ and $y$. This introduces a transformation
\begin{align}
u_{k_{1}k_{2}}'(x, y) = u_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x, y) \exp[if(k_{1}, k_{2})] \tag{3.10}
\end{align}
(...) The nontrivial topology arises when the phase of the wavefunction cannot be determined uniquely and smoothly in the entire magnetic Brillouin zone. The transformation (3.10) implies that the overall phase factor for each state vector $\left| u_{k_{1}k_{2}} \right \rangle$ can be chosen arbitrary. This phase can be determined, for example, by demanding that a component of the state vector $u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x^{0}, y^{0}) = \left\langle x^{0}, y^{0} \right| \left. u_{k_{1} k_{2}} \right\rangle$ us real. However, this convention is not enough to fix the phase on the entire magnetic Brillouin zone, since $u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x^{0}, y^{0})$ vanishes for some $(k_{1}, k_{2})$. The existence of zeros of $u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x, y)$ has been shown in Section II.

During his explanation, he have said that given $(x^{0}, y^{0})$ in the magnetic unit cell, there exists $(k_{1}, k_{2})$ in the magnetic Brillouin zone such that $u_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x^{0}, y^{0}) = 0$. He refers the proof of this to Section II of the same paper, and I think he meant this part:

Writing the wavefunctions as
\begin{align}
u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x, y) = \left| u_{k_{1} k_{2}}(x, y) \right| \exp[i\theta_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x, y)] \tag{2.12}
\end{align}
then one has
\begin{align} 
p = - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int d \boldsymbol{\rm{l}} \cdot \frac{\partial \theta_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x, y)}{d \boldsymbol{\rm{l}}} \tag{2.13}
\end{align}
where $\int d \boldsymbol{\rm{l}}$ represents a counterclockwise line integral around the boundary of the magnetic unit cell. (...) Consider an arrow whose directional angles are given by the phase $\theta_{k_{1} k_{2}}$ of the wavefunction. The arrow rotates $p$ times as we go around the boundary. If we go around clockwise a small circle which contains the zero, the corresponding arrow rotates once either clockwise or counterclockwise. Therefore we can regard a zero of the wavefunction as a vortex which has a vorticity either $1$ or $-1$ corresponding to clockwise or counterclockwise rotation of the arrow, respectively. (...)The magnetic field forces a wavefunction to have $-p$ vorticity in the magnetic unit cell.

But as far as I understand, this only shows that given $(k_{1}, k_{2})$, there exists a point $(x^{0}, y^{0})$ inside the magnetic unit cell that gives $u_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x^{0}, y^{0}) = 0$.
I think this statement is quite different from what he have mentioned in the Section III, because this does not guarantee that for any point in $(x^{0}, y^{0})$ in the magnetic unit cell, you can find $(k_{1}, k_{2})$ that makes $u_{k_{1}k_{2}}(x^{0}, y^{0}) = 0$.
How are these two statement connected?
